# Sample mean of the squares of Standard Normal R.V.s

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Given $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d standard normal variables, the sample mean of the squares is

$$\bar{X^2_n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i = \frac{1}{n}(X^2_1+X^2_2+...+X^2_n)$$

For very large $n$, is the distribution of $\sqrt{n}\big(\bar{X^2_n}-a\big)$ best approximated by a standard normal distribution or chi-squared with $n$ degrees of freedom?

I know that for $Q \sim \chi^2_n$ we have

$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^n X^2_n=X^2_1+X^2_2+...+X^2_n$$

But since $\bar{X^2_n}$ is the sample mean of the squares and not just the sum of the squares, I'm a little doubtful. It makes sense for it to be chi-square but I need to be sure as eventually have to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X^2_n}]$ and $\mathbb{V}[\bar{X^2_n}]$.

Can someone confirm or correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: What is the distribution of $(X_1^2+ X_2^2) /2$? Can we calculate that? Would $1/2$ bother too much?

Comment: I'm not given any data @User1865345 ; what do you mean with $1/2$?

Comment: The answer depends on the meaning of "best" and on what value $a$ might have.  But since $n\bar X^2_n$ has--exactly--a $\chi^2_n$ distribution--there's no need for approximation, leaving us wondering what you are trying to ask.  Are you aware that $E[Q]=E[n\bar X^2_n]=nE[\bar X^2_n]$?

Comment: I'm on the same boat as you @whuber trying to figure out what the problem is actually trying to ask. Yes, "best" is ambiguous and, no, $a$ is not defined so I assume it can take any value. Apparently, the "best" distribution should either be $N(0,1)$, $N(0,2)$, $N(0,n)$, $N(0,2n)$ and $\chi^2_n$. As per your last comment, it should be normal instead but which one is it? I'm still learning please bare with me on this one.

Comment: I wasn't aware that $n\bar X^2_n$ has exactly a $\chi^2_n$ distribution @whuber thanks for pointing that out; logically multiplying $n$ cancels $1/n$ out. The expectation then makes sense since $n$ is a constant and can be factored out. It would be similar to $\mathbb{V}[Q]=\mathbb{V}[n\bar{X^2_n}]=n^2\mathbb{V}[\bar{X^2_n}]$, correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Could someone please answer in simple terms which is the correct one? Thanks

Comment: Since $Q \sim \chi^2_n$ you have $\mathbb E[Q]=n$ and $\mathbb V[Q]=2n$.   As $n$ increases you have $\frac{Q-n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converging in distribution to $N(0,2)$ using the CLT as the sum of i.i.d random variables with mean $1$ and variance $2$.  Since $Q=n \overline{X^2}$ you can also say $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\overline{X^2}-1\right)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ as $n$ increases.  But, as @whuber says, this is unnecessary given that you already have the exact distribution from $n \overline{X^2} \sim \chi^2_n$

Comment: Thanks @Henry for your clarifying comment. Say $A_n:=\bar{X^2_n}$, then it makes perfect sense that $nA_n \sim \chi^2_n$. The next task asks for the mean $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X^2_n}]$ and variance $\mathbb{V}[\bar{X^2_n}]$ of $A_n\big(A_n\bar{X^2_n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i \big)$ and explicitly points out to "note that you're not asked about $n\bar{X^2_n}$; there is no factor $n$ in front". This is precisely what whuber asked if I was aware of. Also, $\alpha$ should be the limit in probability of $A_n$. Can I proceed with computing the expectation and variance of a $\chi^2_n$ r.v. or not?